# Reset facebook like url for pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We've had few pages on our site which were open only for signed-in users. However, the urls of these pages were shared on facebook and whenever facebook visited these pages it got redirected to common page which is shown for non signed-in users.

Now, we have opened these pages for all and implemented like button on these pages. And whenever someone likes one page it gets reflected on other pages as well, I am assuming this is because facebook internally still thinks all point to same url.
However, I am setting the href attribute to these pages, still it doesn't work.

Is there a way where I can reset the counter for these pages and make facebook treat these as new pages? I did try passing few GET params, still it shows old counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the URLs into this Facebook Lint form (or make requests to this page with the proper parameters from an application) and it will clear Facebook's cache of those pages.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yes Alex, I figured that out. I saw your post after I posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to make facebook re-crawl these pages again. I could have waited for 24hrs, which is the frequency with which facebook crawls pages. I chose to use facebook linter, which makes facebook query the url immediately

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug